# How To Auto Complete Jquery Use with My Js Function All Code Is Attached?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

i am getting city state by entering zipcode using google map api my code is below,

google map api link,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Script for getting city state via zip code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var zip =document.getElementById("txtZip").value;
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': zip }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': results[0].geometry.location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    var loc = getCityState(results);
                    document.getElementById("TextBox1").value=loc;
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }); 

function getCityState(results)
    {
        var a = results[0].address_components;
        var city, state;
        for(i = 0; i <  a.length; ++i)
        {
           var t = a[i].types;
           if(compIsType(t, 'administrative_area_level_1'))
              state = a[i].long_name; //store the state
           else if(compIsType(t, 'locality'))
              city = a[i].long_name; //store the city
        }
        return (city + ', ' + state)
    }

function compIsType(t, s) { 
       for(z = 0; z < t.length; ++z) 
          if(t[z] == s)
             return true;
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

enter zip code value and showing city state in textbox "TextBox1" shown below,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtZip"  runat="server" ToolTip="Enter Zip"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray"></asp:TextBox>
```

how to use this jquery script with my JS for auto complete??

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Hopes for your suggetions

Comment: Is this not the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229833/how-to-auto-complete-city-state-by-entering-zipcode-through-java-script-my-code)?

Comment: Where is your html object with id="tags"? I think you may need to swap that for the clientid of your asp.net textbox with id txtZip.

Comment: Please describe in what way this does not work. Are you getting any js errors?

Comment: @geedubb i wanna auto complete city and state as user enter zip then how will we do that using jquery auto complete as i am just populating city state when user enter zip code

Comment: @geeddubb if i swap id with txtzip then it will check it from sorce attached i want it to use my js function which is getting city state which is mentioned seperatly in script

Comment: Try to view page source. Grab the actual id of the textbox called txtzip and update your jquery aurocomplete code to reference that id, instead of  #tags.

Comment: @geedub i get you but how would i use my code for the city state as i am getting city state via zip entered and how to use that function in autocomplete source ??